# Mysql order by and random not working

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table,

```
id  price   saleprice
1   4500    4250
2   5250    5100
3   4850    4200
4   2850    2350
```

and my query is

```
SELECT *,(price-saleprice) as newprice  
  FROM `products` 
 order by  newprice desc, rand() LIMIT 3
```

Here random is not working, what is the problem?

Comment: What is the outcome of your query and what should it be?

Comment: You probably have too few records so Rand appears to not work.

Comment: If I write rand(), newprice its coming randomly, but the newprice not proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newprice` values are 250,150,650 and 500. These are all different values. Your results will we ordered by this column and only then, if you have a "tie", those will be sorted randomly.

Answer (score 1):

None of your rows share the same newprice, so the rand() is not necessary. The 'order by newprice' is sufficient.

Comment: top 3 should come randomly

Comment: top 3 newprice is 250, 150 and 450, so will be ordered 3,1,2

Comment: these 3 should come randomly like, 3,2,1 1,3,2

Comment: But the top 3 all have different newprice, so the rand is not used. They are sorted on newprice which is different for each of them. How are the top 3 different to the 4th row ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *,MAX(price-saleprice) as newprice  
FROM `products` 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY  newprice desc, rand() LIMIT 3
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56fa1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (*grab randomly three products and order them descending by new price*)?

```
SELECT *, (price - saleprice) newprice  
  FROM
(
  SELECT *
    FROM `products` 
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 3 
) q
  ORDER BY newprice DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f597/3)** demo